# Export pyLDAvis graphs as standalone webpage

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

i am analysing text with topic modelling and using Gensim and pyLDAvis for that. Would like to share the results with distant colleagues, without a need for them to install python and all required libraries. 
Is there a way to export interactive graphs as HTML/JS files that could be uploaded to any web server?
I've found something mentioned in documentation, but have no idea how to implement it:
**https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/pyLDAvis/_display.py**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

pyLDAvis.save_html should work:

```
p = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(topic_model, corpus, dictionary)
pyLDAvis.save_html(p, 'lda.html')
```